# Speed up python 3.5 loop to run it as fast as python could be

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, cython

I need to calculate distance between 2 xyz points in massive data (100 Gb, about 20 trylion points). I am trying to speed up this loop. I created KDtree, add parallel calculation's, split my array to smaller parts. So i guess all left to speed up is this loop. My pure python calculation time took about 10 hours 42 minutes. Adding numpy reduce time to 5 hours and 34 minutes. Adding numba speed it up to 4h 15 minutes. But it is still not fast enough. I heard that Cython is the fastest way for python calculation's but i don't have any experience in c and I don't know how to translate my function to cython code.   How can i get this loop to run faster, using cython or any other way?

```
def controller(point_array, las_point_array):  

    empty = []


    tree = spatial.cKDTree(point_array, leafsize=1000, copy_data = True)   

    empty = __pure_calc(las_point_array, point_array, empty, tree)  

    return ptList   

#############################################################################################

@autojit
def __pure_calc(las_point_array, point_array, empty, tree):

    for i in las_point_array:
            p = tree.query(i)   

            euc_dist = math.sqrt(np.sum((point_array[p[1]]-i)**2))  

            ##add one row at a time to empty list
            empty.append([i[0], i[1], i[2], euc_dist, point_array[p[1]][0], point_array[p[1]][1], point_array[p[1]][2]]) 

    return empty
```

I attach sample data for testing:

[Sample](https://ufile.io/rq0ea)

Comment: The fact is your runtime is going to be pretty bad. You could maybe use fast inverse square root, but you're still applying a squaring factor internally. All the operations you have to use here are higher than linear, so slowish runtime is just reality without some fancy manipulation.

Comment: If you only need the closest point and not the real distance, get rid of the `sqrt`. It's a costly operation that doesn't change the order of the distances.

Comment: I would reccomend  you to try other interpreters. [link](https://pypy.org/) PyPy it's a very fast JIT interpreter that will certrainly give you a lot of speed.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I still need distance between points.

Comment: @Mikael Pypy for python 3.5 is now on beta stage and also is not supporting Win64

Comment: Are you implementing a KDTree? Have you tried `scipy.spatial.KDTree`?

Comment: Would it be a great problem to switch to 3.4? I mean, speed in Python is best achieved using PyPy or ShedSkin.

Comment: @tkerwin  For sample data i tested scipy.spatial.cKdtree (195 sec), scipy.spatial.Kdtree (423 sec), sklearn.Kdtree(297 sec), sklearn.Balltree (308 sec). The fastest from this is scipy.spatial.cKdtree.

Comment: @Mikael My calculation are just a part of whole project all other machines and programs are using python 3.5

Comment: Start with identifying what is actually taking most of execution time. cProfile module will help here. Can then determine what needs changing to improve it. Yes, Cython is a good bet for tight loops that do calculations in python code which I doubt is where this code is bottlenecked at.

Comment: It might help if you told us which variables in your code are scalars, lists and/or arrays (and if arrays, the shape).  For scalars, `math.sqrt` is faster than `np.sqrt`.

Comment: I have a gut feeling that if you just collected `[i,p]` for all `j`, then you could calculate `distM` with one array operation.  But when I tried to set up a test case, I found that I had no idea what the various inputs might look like.  I'm tempted to close this question for lack of a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please see my edits.

Comment: I'm not really sure how the current answer is out-dated, given that it and the question is less than a month old?

Comment: Damit i put wrong label... i should give bount with more attention.. Can i change it now somehow? Anyway i will accept any answer which will improve speed significantly.

Comment: if your points are often the same distance from one another, you could memoize the results of the sqrt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to utilize vectorized functions as much as possible since any call to a pure python function inside the loop will more or less make the autojit pointless (the bottleneck will be the pure function call).
I noticed that the query function is vectorizable, and so is the euclidian distance calculation. 
I'm not sure what your ptList variable in the controller function is (the example is a bit faulty), but assuming it is the output of your jit function, or close enfough to it, you should be able to do something like this:

```
def controller(point_array, las_point_array):

    tree = spatial.cKDTree(point_array, leafsize=1000, copy_data = True)
    distances, pt_idx = tree.query(las_point_array)
    nearest_pts = point_array[pt_idx]
    euc_distances = np.sqrt((nearest_pts - las_point_array).sum(axis=1) ** 2)
    result = np.vstack((las_point_array.T, euc_distances.T, nearest_pts.T)).T

    return result
```

Comment: can you please explain me why you calculate "distances" at this lane "distances, pt_idx = tree.query(las_point_array)".

Comment: Ok i tested your code after changing "result = np.vstack((veg_point_array.T, distances.T, nearest_pts.T)).T" that line it calculate exacly what i want and is really fast almost 93% faster than my previous method. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

Your function builds a list (`closestPt`) that ends up looking like this:

```
[
    [i0[0], i0[1], i0[2], distM0],
    [i1[0], i1[1], i1[2], distM1],
    ...
]
```

The first thing you should do is to preallocate the entire result as a NumPy array (`np.empty()`), and write into it one row at a time.  This will avoid a ton of memory allocations.  Then you will note that you can defer the `sqrt()` to the very end, and run it on the `distM` column after your loops are all done.

There may be more optimization opportunities if you post a full working test harness with random/sample input data.

Comment: To make a simple (N,4) array, the list append approach is consistently 2+ faster than the `np.empty` one, at least for N up to 10000000 (11 v 22 sec).